# Spring DAO exception translation inside transaction

Tags: java, spring, exception, dao

I'm using `Spring 3.1.2` with `Hibernate 4`.

I have a DAO implementation class `MyDaoImpl` annotated with `@Repository` so that exception translation is enabled. I have a service class `MyService` annotated with `@Transactional` as follows:

```
public class MyService implements IMyService {

    private MyDao myDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setMyDao(MyDao dao) {
       this.myDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void createA(String name)
    {
        A newA = new A(name);
        this.myDao.saveA(newA);
    }
}
```

I've wrote a unit tests class `MyServiceTest` as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:beans.xml" })
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class MyServiceTest implements IMyServiceTest {

    private IMyService myService;

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setMyService(IMyService myService)
    {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Test
    @Override
    public void testCreateA()
    {
       //Assume that there is already a row of table A with the name "A1"
       //so I expect to get a Spring DataAccessException (or subtypes) 
       //when the session is flushed
       this.myService.createA("A1");

       this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

       //asserts
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I get a Hibernate specific exception `ConstraintViolationException`. I've found on the forum that this is because the translation system takes place outside the transaction, so in this case after `testCreateA()` returns. I don't know if this is the real cause, but if it is, it means that I can't test that the translation works for my DAOs. One solution would be to remove the `@Transactional` annotations from my unit tests, but I would no benefit from the rollback feature.

What are your recommendations?

---

**EDIT:** I've added the `SessionFactory` declared in my context to the test class, so that I can access the current session for flushing.

Some additional explanations: In this case, I get the exception when the session is flushed (which is inside the transaction). I flush the session in order to avoid false positives as it is explained in the docs. Also, since the default propagation is REQUIRED, the `testCreateA()` transaction is also used for the call to `createA()`, so the changes are not flushed (generally) until `testCreateA()` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` bean defination? Like

```
   <!--
        Post-processor to perform exception translation on @Repository classes
        (from native exceptions such as JPA PersistenceExceptions to
        Spring's DataAccessException hierarchy).
    -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

From [Spring doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/dao/annotation/PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.html).

> Bean post-processor that automatically applies persistence exception
>   translation to any bean that carries the `@Repository` annotation, adding
>   a corresponding `PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor` to the exposed
>   proxy (either an existing AOP proxy or a newly generated proxy that
>   implements all of the target's interfaces).
>
> Translates native resource exceptions to Spring's `DataAccessException`
>   hierarchy. Autodetects beans that implement the
>   `PersistenceExceptionTranslator` interface, which are subsequently asked
>   to translate candidate exceptions

Comment: I didn't see this in the doc http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/dao.html. Are you sure it is still relevant?

Comment: @Mickael: AFAIK `@Repository` indicates class for exception translation and `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` do the translation task. Check my edit.

Comment: I've edited my question. Adding the post processor doesn't solve my problem, I still get a Hibernate specific exception inside the test case.